# External dependencies / Header files

Tags: header-files, external-dependencies

In a windows MSVC6.0 compiler, if there is a workspace with one project in it, what files would be in the **Header Files**  folder  and what files would be in the **External Dependencies** folder?

I thought those files which are explicitly included (#include <*.h>  are to be in the **Header Files** folder and thsoe which are in turn included by added header files, will be in **External Dependencies** folder? But doesnt seem to be case.

So what is the difference between the two?

-AD

Answer (score 2):

Header files listed as external dependencies are not analysed and available in the class view tab.  Moving a file from external dependencies to header files includes it into the class view.

Answer (score 1):

The folders in the tree view are purely for your convenience (at least in vs200x - I don' remember ever changing hem in vc6).
You can rename them to anything you want and put any files in any folder you want.
I generally create folders based on the parts of the program (ie gui, server, fileIO ) and put the header and cpp files for classes in the same folder so I can quickly find the definition and declaration.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the structure of header files and #include *.h in the workspace i found following:

1.) Those files which are not explicitly added to the Projects **Header Files** folder, but are nonetheless included using the #include directive, by different header and source files, are added to the project automatically by MSVC under the folder **External Dependencies**

But now i have a question, is it better to let MSVC add those header files as **External Dependencies** or is it better to add it explicitly in the **Header Files** folder, or is there no difference in the two?

-AD